# Values added wont save in the node

Tags: c, nodes

Please help values wont save once added into the list and nothing is printed as a result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node{
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char address[100];
    char postal[6];
    char number[10];
    struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node node;


void print(node* root);
node* add(node* root);
void addinfo(node* root);

int main(){
    node* root=NULL;
    root=add(root);
    print(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Its supposed to add a new node at the end of the list then add values

```
node* add(node* root){
    if(root==NULL){
        root=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));      
        addinfo(root);
        root->next=NULL;
        return root;
    }
    node* temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    addinfo(temp);
    temp->next=NULL;
    return root;

}

void print(node* root){
    node* temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        printf("First Name: %s\n",temp->first);
        printf("Last Name:%s\n",temp->last);
        printf("Address:%s\n",temp->address);
        printf("Postal%s\n",temp->postal);
        printf("Phone Number:%s\n",temp->number);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

If I print in the function, the values print normally but once this functions ends all the values are gone.

```
void addinfo(node* root){
    node* temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Please enter a name:");
    gets(temp->first);

    printf("Please enter a last name:");
    gets(temp->last);

    printf("Please enter an address:");
    gets(temp->address);

    printf("Please enter a postal code:");
    gets(temp->postal);

    printf("Please enter a phone number:");
    gets(temp->number);
}
```

Comment: You're walking a pointer down your list to NULL, then forgetting where you were and changing that pointer, but doing nothing to the underlying list. Nowhere do you link the newly allocated node to the tail of the list. (comments about `gets()` withheld, other than to say *stop using it*).

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks I understand that but how do I link the newly allocated node to the end of the of the list? (First time working with  nodes, really bad with this lol)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of implementing what you want is keeping a pointer to the last item of a list:

```
typedef struct list {
    node *first;
    node *last;
} list;
```

Then you initialize a list with

```
list alist = { NULL, NULL };
```

and add items as follows:

```
void addNewNode(list *plist, node *pnode)
{
    pnode->next = NULL;
    if( plist->first == NULL)
        plist->first = pnode;
    else
        plist->last->next = pnode; 
    plist->last = pnode;
}
```

fill the list:

```
while(there_is_something_to_read())
{
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    addInfo(newnode);
    addNewNode(&alist, newnode);
}
```

note however, `addInfo()` should do just what its name says: add info to the node; no list manipulation:

```
void addinfo(node* pnode){
    printf("Please enter a name:");
    gets(pnode->first);
    // .........
    printf("Please enter a phone number:");
    gets(pnode->number);
}
```

print it:

```
node *pnode;
for(pnode = alist.first; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next)
    printNode(pnode);
```

with

```
void printNode(node *pnode)
{
    printf( "first name: %s\n", pnode->first);
    //...
    printf( "phone: %s\n", pnode->number);
    printf( "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
void addinfo(node* root){
    node* temp=root;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You carefully traverse the entire list until `temp` is NULL (which could be achieved more swiftly by writing `temp = NULL;` and then you overwrite the NULL with newly allocated memory, but don't hook the new node into the list.

This function cannot be used on an empty list.  It can be revised to work on a non-empty list:

```
void addinfo(node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;  // Report error?
    node *temp = root;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp->next == NULL)
        return;  // Report error?
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;

    …other code as before…
}
```